# Outlook flag an email and move it to a folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Is there a script that would allow me to flag an email in outlook and then automatically move it to a folder?

I found the following that will copy selected email and move it, but I need it to flag it as well;

```
Outlook VB Macro to move selected mail item(s) to a target folder
Sub MoveToFiled()
On Error Resume Next

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim moveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Define path to the target folder
Set moveToFolder = ns.Folders("Mailbox - Jim Merrell").Folders("@Filed")

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox ("No item selected")
Exit Sub
End If

If moveToFolder Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Target folder not found!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Move Macro Error"
End If

For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
If moveToFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
  If objItem.Class = olMail Then
     objItem.move moveToFolder
  End If
End If
Next

Set objItem = Nothing
Set moveToFolder = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```

Cheers,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

in the end the follwoing line should do the Job:

```
    mail.FlagRequest = "text you need"
```

or if you also want to set reminders etc. use this

```
Sub flag_the_mail(mail As mailitem, flagre as string, tm As String)
On Error GoTo ende
        mail.MarkAsTask olMarkNoDate
        mail.FlagRequest = flagre 
    If tm <> "00:00:00 09:00" Then
        mail.TaskStartDate = tm
        mail.TaskDueDate = tm
        mail.ReminderSet = True
        mail.ReminderTime = tm
    Else
        mail.TaskStartDate = "01.01.4501"
        mail.TaskDueDate = "01.01.4501"
        mail.ReminderSet = False
        mail.ReminderTime = "00:00:00"
    End If
        mail.Save
ende:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox ("Fehler in 'Kennzeichensetzen': " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description)
End Sub
```

tm - which is the date - comes as a text here, e.g. "03.11.2014 09:00"

I hope this helps,

Max